# Input from STDIN to array

Tags: perl

All of the following seem to work. But are the equivalent?

Approach 1:

```
chomp(my @array = <STDIN>);
```

Approach 2:

```
my @array;  
chomp(@array = <>);
```

Approach 3:

```
chomp(my @array = <>);
```

Comment: Input from `<>` comes either from standard input, or from each file listed on the command line. See [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators) for more information. The position of declaring `my @array` does not make a difference though, so approach 2 and 3 are identical. Approach 1 will be indentical to 2 and 3 if there is no arguments in `@ARGV` (that is on the command line)

Comment: There is no _best pattern_. One of the core ideas behind Perl is that [there is more than one way to do it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it). Often one of several possible ways is more suited for a specific use case, because it's faster, shorter, easier to read or easier to maintain. All of those have merit. If you're just beginning your journey into programming, use the way that feels most comfortable for you, and make sure you are consistent. The rest will come with time. :)

Answer (score 5):

The first reads from `STDIN` instead of `ARGV`. `ARGV` is a "magical" handle that reads from each of the files listed in `@ARGV` in turn, or from `STDIN` if `@ARGV` is empty.

The last two are identical.

Comment: @melpomene, That's not exactly right either. Basically, `@ARGV` isn't expected to be a list of file names so much as a list of arguments to pass to 2-arg `open`, which means it can be `gunzip -c foo.gz |` or `-` . I was keeping things simple. [Example](https://pastebin.com/UxG0hjdw)

Comment: But primarily, I didn't want to promote this misfeature. All programs should probably use [ARGV::readonly](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ARGV::readonly) or similar for security purposes. In Linux, you can use `/proc/self/fd/0`, and there are also shell features you can use (assuming you're in some odd situation where you can't simply leave out `-`).

Comment: Oh, that's a fun module. If you `use` it twice by accident, it'll break your `@ARGV`.

Comment: @melpomene, The guts could have been placed at the top level instead of in `import`, but this way the module can be loaded without triggering the behaviour. A flag could prevent it from "escaping" twice, but I don't really see the need. The feature I see as missing is the ability to perform the "escaping" at runtime. This would allow runtime use of `GetOptions`, for example. That can be done using `use ARGV::readonly qw( ); ... ARGV::readonly->import(); ...`, but that's not clean. Simple to fix the module in a backwards compatible way, though